# Display Grid while using Device Camera in android.

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to display grid while using camera on android device.One might have seen it if you have used instagram before.Something like shown in image below.How can I implement it in my code for my app.please provide some useful link,suggestions or tutorials for same.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use SurfaceView to display your video, check this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/camera-preview-on-surfaceview.html) for example; how to take video, and the following code for how to make a custom SurfaceView to show the grid.

```
class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        PreviewCallback {

    public MySurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        // TODO draw grid
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO handle camera frames

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        initCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        releaseCamera();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite ondraw method and use this ..

```
        Paint redPaint = new Paint();
          redPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
          redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawLine((canvas.getWidth()/2)-size-20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)-size-20, (canvas.getWidth()/2)-size-20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)+size+20, redPaint);
        canvas.drawLine((canvas.getWidth()/2)+size+20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)-size-20, (canvas.getWidth()/2)-size-20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)-size-20, redPaint);
        canvas.drawLine((canvas.getWidth()/2)-size-20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)+size+20, (canvas.getWidth()/2)+size+20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)+size+20, redPaint);
        canvas.drawLine((canvas.getWidth()/2)+size+20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)+size+20, (canvas.getWidth()/2)+size+20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)-size-20, redPaint);
        canvas.drawLine((canvas.getWidth()/2)-(size/60), (canvas.getHeight()/2)-size-20, (canvas.getWidth()/2)+(size/60), (canvas.getHeight()/2)+size+20, redPaint);
        canvas.drawLine((canvas.getWidth()/2)+size+20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)-(size/60), (canvas.getWidth()/2)-size-20, (canvas.getHeight()/2)-(size/60), redPaint);
```

Comment: what should be for size ?